# Error while building kafka source using gradle

Tags: gradle, apache-kafka

I have executed the following commands:

```
   $cd /opt/kafka-0.8.2.1-src/
   $gradle
```

Following error is coming:

Building project 'core' with Scala version 2.10.4
:downloadWrapper

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not create service of type TaskArtifactStateCacheAccess using TaskExecutionServices.createCacheAccess().

  > Failed to create parent directory '/opt/kafka-0.8.2.1-src/.gradle' when creating directory '/opt/kafka-0.8.2.1-src/.gradle/2.4/taskArtifacts'
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.511 secs

I cannot figure out what is going wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Set your GRADLE_USER_HOME variable to a folder where the user (running Gradle process) has valid "w" write access. It's basically where Gradle is trying to setup a **.gradle** folder to create/store it's cache data.

For ex:

```
GRADLE_USER_HOME=~/.gradle
```

or

```
GRADLE_USER_HOME=/some/folder/where/I/have/valid/rwx/access/.gradle
```

or

```
GRADLE_USER_HOME=~/my_gradle_2_3_cache/.gradle
```

That'll resolve it.

Run `gradle someTaskYouLike` and you'll now see $GRADLE_USER_HOME folder containing *native* and *caches* folder in it.